# What is happening with the last element of the array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So, I'm trying to solve the excercise in https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/

I came up with this solution (which I have tested succesfully with shorter arrays of about 5-7 elements)

```js
class ListNode {
    val: number
    next: ListNode | null
    constructor(val?: number, next?: ListNode | null) {
        this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
        this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
    }
}

var l1 = new ListNode(1, new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0 , new ListNode(0, new ListNode(0 , new ListNode(0, new ListNode(1)))))))))))))))))))));
var l2 = new ListNode(5, new ListNode(6, new ListNode(4)));

function addTwoNumbers(l1: ListNode | null, l2: ListNode | null): ListNode | null {
    let r1 = [], r2 = [];
    
    while(l1 !== null)
    {
        r1.push(l1.val);
        l1 = l1.next;
    }
    
    while(l2 !== null)
    {
        r2.push(l2.val);
        l2 = l2.next;
    }

    console.log(r1); console.log(r2);
    
    r1.reverse(); r2.reverse();
    let n1, n2;
    
    n1 = Number(r1.join(''))
    n2 = Number(r2.join(''))
    
    let n3 = n1 + n2;
    let newN3 = n3.toString().split('').reverse();
    
    console.log(`N1: ${n1} N2: ${n2} N3: ${n3} newN3: ${newN3.toString()}`);

    let l3 : ListNode[] = [];
    
    for(let i = 0 ; i < newN3.length ; i ++)
        l3.push(new ListNode(Number(newN3[i]),null));
    
    for(let i = 0 ; i < l3.length ; i++)
        l3[i].next = l3[i+1]??null;

    return l3[0];
};

let salida = addTwoNumbers(l1,l2);
console.log(salida);
while(salida !== null)
{
    console.log('Num; ', salida.val);
    salida = salida.next;
}
```

However, when I tried it with that 21-element `l1` array, it seems that it ignores the last element from the  array. The output of that is:

```
[
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
]
[ 5, 6, 4 ]
N1: 100000000000000000000 N2: 465 N3: 100000000000000000000 newN3: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
ListNode {
  val: 0,
  next: ListNode { val: 0, next: ListNode { val: 0, next: [ListNode] } }
}
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  0
Num;  1
```

Note that N1 should be 100000000000000000001, and outputs 100000000000000000000. And the sum of N1+N2 is wrong.

Comment: `100000000000000000000 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` you're running into inaccuracies due to the number type: `100000000000000000000 + 1 === 100000000000000000000`

Comment: BigInt might be useful here

Comment: The idea of the exercise is to implement addition *without* converting the lists to numbers. Do you remember how to add numbers, starting with the rightmost digits, and then continuing to the left, passing a possible carry to the next column?

Comment: Couldn't resist solving the problem myself: https://gist.github.com/md2perpe/b257e1d1df3381c67464778de370fb1b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For larger Integer please use BigInt instead of Number, replace Number with BigInt and you will be good to go

```
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER // 9007199254740991
```

[MDN Number Max Safe Integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

[BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)